# How to convert into JPQL for inline view?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a question.

In MySQL, I can query as below, but I can't do that in JPQL because JPA 2.1 is not supported for inline view.

`select a2.level from (select level from alarm where sensor_id = 32 order by id desc limit 1) as a2 where a2.level = 'warning';`

[select * from alarm where sensor_id = 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUmYh.png)

I wanna find whether there is latest data which is level = 'warning'.

First solution I'm thinking is that converting into JPQL.

Second solution is writing in native query.

I don't know how to do both of them. Please help me out.

thanks!

Comment: Wait the inline query returns only one row; Why do you need sub query?

Comment: I need an inline query to find latest data which is sensor_id = 32...

Comment: Still don't understand why you need inline query; you can even check this in code as well instead of making a inline query